# Angular-material Date-Picker doesn't work

Tags: javascript, .net, angularjs, datepicker, angular-material

Can anyone help me why angular-material date-picker doesn't work?
  My cshtml have the following code:

```
  <label>Date and time</label>
    <md-content>
        <md-datepicker ng-model="viewModel.employee.contractExpireDate" md-placeholder="Enter date">

        </md-datepicker>
    </md-content>
```

And i have the following dependencies

```
var companyApp = angular.module('company', ['ui.router', 'ngResource','ngAria','ngAnimate', 'ngMaterial']);
```

Do i need to add something or to install any package except angular-material?

Comment: Can you share a fiddle or Plunker ?

Comment: Working fine for me... https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/suunyz3e/208/

Answer (score 0):

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        // Need to add a dependency on the 'ui.bootstrap' module to use
        // Angular-UI Bootstrap
        var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

        app.controller('MyDateController', function ($scope) {
            $scope.date = new Date();
            $scope.date.setSeconds(0);
        });
    </script>
<div ng-controller="MyDateController">

        <div style="width: 300px">
            <input type="text"
                class="form-control"
                datepicker-popup="yyyy/MM/dd"
                ng-disabled="isOpen"
                ng-model="date"
                is-open="isOpen"
                ng-click="isOpen = true" />
        </div>
        <h2>Time</h2>
        <timepicker ng-model="date">
        </timepicker>
        <hr>
        <h2>Currently Selected Date: {{date | date:'medium'}}
        </h2>
    </div>
```